# 2" o/d aluminum pipe (1/4" wall) used as 10' 'axle' to 'roll' dock out of water

Tags: strength, aluminum

I'm curious how much weight this 'axle' could support? The dock wheels on ends are capable of 700 lbs each.

The dock itself is 10’ wide. The axle will be placed under two 4’ x 2’ rigid black nylon dock floats. There is a 2’ gap in the centre where the axle/bar will not be supported. The two wheels are on the outside near the ends of the axle/pipe. It won’t be exactly 12’, likely a little less.

In addition the possibility exists to add two more wheels located in the centre if the ‘axle’ in that 2’ gap between the floats that I mentioned..

The terrain is somewhat rocky and uneven.

Comment: An engineer would want to know your user specifications. How much flexing is permissible? Where will the load be mounted on the axle? Close to the wheels (much reduced bending) or closer to the centre (mucho bending). Hit the [Edit] link ... add a drawing with some dimensions ...

Comment: see above for updated description